Basis of the sum of subspaces

Find the basis of the sum and intersection of subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ in $R^{2 \times 2}$ if they are spanned by vectors: $$V_1: A_1= \begin{pmatrix}
3 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, A_2= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, A_3=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$V_2: B_1= \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
5 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, B_2= \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 \\
6 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, B_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
-2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The sum of subspaces comprises vectors characterized as $v=v_1+v_2$, where $v_1 \in V_1, v_2 \in V_2$. First, I expressed each space as a linear combination of basis vectors and determined the dimensions.
$V_1: 
v_1=a_1 \begin{pmatrix}
3 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}+a_2 \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}+a_3 \begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
To verify linear independence, I encoded the linear combinations as a matrix corresponding to a homogeneous system of linear equations.
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 3 \\
-2 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Given that the dimension of the subspace $V_1$ is two, I eliminated matrix $A_3$ from the basis. Is it permissible to eliminate any matrix arbitrarily?
Similarly, I managed the same with the subspace $V_2$. Subsequently, I wrote down a vector from the sum of the subspaces and replicated the process I used with $V_1$:
$$ v=v_1+v_2=c_1 \begin{pmatrix}
3 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}+c_2 \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}+c_3 \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
5 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}+c_4 \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
-2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$
The basis I obtained was:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
-2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I selected matrices to be eliminated from the basis at random.
After some time, I decided to try a different approach. I simply wrote in a row all the corresponding coefficients of six matrices, reduced to row echelon form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 3&3&3&0 \\
-2 & 1 &-1&1&0&2 \\
0 & 1 &1&5&6&-2 \\
1 & 0 &1&0&-1&2 \\
\end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1&1&1&0 \\
0 & 1 &1&3&2&2 \\
0 & 0 &0&1&2&-2 \\
0 & 0 &0&0&0&0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Based on the 1st, 2nd, and 4th columns, I selected matrices $A_1, A_2,$ and $B_1$ as the basis elements:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
5 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Consequently, I ended up with somewhat varied bases. Are both alternatives valid, or is my entire approach flawed?


Is it permissable to eliminate any matrix arbitrarily.


Nope. For example, consider $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent. Suppose we have $v, 2v, u$, upon computing that the dimension is $2$, if we eliminate $u$, then the dimension is $1$.

For the case when the dimension is $2$, we just have to pick $2$ elements that are not multiples of each other.

Your first approach is just computing the basis of each subspace but we are not answering the question of computing the basis of the sum of the subspaces.



Your second approach is correct. We identify the pivot columns and the corresponding matrices would form a basis.
Note that it is possible to obtain a different set of basis since basis is not unique. For example, by permuting the columns before we perform the Gaussian Elimination, a different set of matrices could have been chosen.
